# Convert regex string from Java to Python

Tags: java, python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following function in Java to replace occurrences of a regex with a blank space:

```
string.replaceAll("\r?\n[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*", " ")
```

In Python, the equivalent would be:

```
re.sub("\r?\n[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*", " ", string)
```

But I just realised that Python doesn't parse regex strings the same way as Java. My question is what is the Python equivalent regex string of `\r?\n[\\s&&[^\r\n]]*` ?

Comment: Could you add some example what exactly the regex should and should not match? Also, have you _tried_ the regex? Do you have evidence that it does not behave the same as in Java?

Comment: Python has the nice feature of literal strings: stick an `r` in front of the string - `r"\n\r"` - and those are treated as literal backslashes, not escape characters.

Comment: @tobias_k Perhaps, but ["Usually patterns will be expressed in Python code using this raw string notation."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: @tobias_k I Java if I have `String s = "aap\nnoot  "`, I get the result `aap noot` but in Python I get `aap *newline* noot`. Hence it does not behave the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, it would be

```
re.sub(r'\r?\n(?:(?![\r\n])\s)*', " ", stri)
```

You may use the same regex in java also.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning behind this, but it works! Thanks.

Comment: `(?:(?![\r\n])\s)*` would match any space character but not of line break or carriage return , zero or more times

Comment: for those wondering `r'somestring'` is a "raw" string literal. in those any blackslashes are not used to represent special characters. this is most often used in regex since in 99% of cases you don't want those special characters in there (and IMO makes the regex string more readable)